# Clearfix Issues

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="parent">
    <div style="float:left;">
        Content 1
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>


CSS:

.parent {
    normal styling for parent
}

.parent:before,
.parent:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.parent:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

The issue is that for some reason the parent's height is larger than it's suppose to be. If I remove the :before and :after stylings then the parent's height is normal but of course then I loose the clearfix.

I'm wondering how can I ensure that the parent's height doesn't change after introducing these extra stylings.

This is what I mean

Without the :before and :after stylings

```
------------------------------------------
\content1                        content2\
------------------------------------------
```

With the :before and :after styling

```
------------------------------------------
\content1                        content2\
\                                        \
------------------------------------------
```

for some reason it introduces extra space when there is no need for it.

Comment: It's fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/rWm6S/

Comment: Parent: http://i.imgur.com/3svMRx6.png
Child 1: http://i.imgur.com/wWp1n0n.png
Child 2: http://i.imgur.com/txmPRPz.png
Styling on the side: http://i.imgur.com/STVpE7h.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to define height in pseudo element:

```
.parent {
    border: 2px solid red;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
.parent:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/nesumimato/edit?html,css,js,output